# mysql Update a column

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-update

i am new to Mysql in vb.net.

what I want is when I click the save button, I want the mysql database is updated and that the collumn Wcoins get updated and it will get a value that is in Label2.Text

my code:

```
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=REMOVED;Port=REMOVED; user id=REMOVED; password=REMOVED; database=REMOVED")
    Dim username As Boolean = True
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE * FROM NewTable WHERE Wcoins=label2.text"
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    command.Connection = conn
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    data = command.ExecuteReader

    data.Close()
    conn.Close()
```

i made some mistakes but i was trying to update Wcoins so it will delete the old value and it will get the value that is displayed in label2.text

any help would be realy apreciated

i'm dutch so if you see spelling mistakes please correct them

Comment: I think you need to review a bit of SQL before. [Update Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahh i tried some codes and i found a working one.

Code:

```
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=REMOVED;Port=REMOVED; user id=REMOVED; password=REMOVED; database=REMOVED")
    Dim username As Boolean = True
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE NewTable SET Wcoins='" & Label2.Text & "' WHERE Name='" & Label1.Text & "';"
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    command.Connection = conn
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    data = command.ExecuteReader

    data.Close()
    conn.Close()
```

thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the Update SQL statement is

```
 UPDATE <table> SET <field>=<value> WHERE <PrimaryKey> = <valueForPK>
```

So your correct command text should be something like

```
 UPDATE NewTable SET Wcoins = <value> WHERE ????? = ??????
```

I don't know what is the name of the Primary Key of your table and this is essential to give you a correct answer because without the WHERE part the UPDATE command will change every record of your table and I suppose that this is not your intention,

Finally, you code is wrong because an UPDATE command (like INSERT or DELETE) will be executed using the MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() and not using the ExecuteReader.
There are other point to underline in your code like the string concatenation to form the command text (Sql Injection and parsing errors) but at this point it is better to fix first the UPDATE problem.

**EDIT** Now that you have given more info on your column's name I could update my answer to show how I would write that code

```
Dim sqlquery = "UPDATE NewTable SET Wcoins=@newValue WHERE Name=@nameValue"
Using conn = New MySqlConnection(.........)
Using command = New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
    conn.Open()
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", label2.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameValue", label1.Text)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

- [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to be certain that the connection is Always closed
  even if you have an exception
- Parameters to add the value for your command without using string
  concatenations ([Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work))
- ExecuteNonQuery for an UPDATE query instead of using a DataAdapter
  and all the necessary code for it